# Возврат значения из функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, где необходимо высчитать player.health после проведения атаки противником, чтобы определять вызывать ли потом нового противника через

`if (player.health > 0 && enemy.health <= 0) {
 myTimer = setInterval(game.makeFightEnviroment, 5000);
}`

Однако есть проблема, что функция снизу не хочет сохранять это значение. Через return все не работает вовсе, функция просто не вызывается

```
      if (enemy.health <= 0) {
    alert("YOU WON A POTATO!");
    getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + player.health;
    getEnemyHealth.innerHTML = "Health: 0";
  } else {
    getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + player.health;
    getEnemyHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + enemy.health;
    //ПРОТИВНИК АТАКУЕТ
    let enemyAttackValues = enemyAttack();
    let totalDamage = enemyAttackValues[0];
    player.health = player.health - totalDamage;
    alert("Получено урона: " + enemyAttackValues[0]);
    if (player.health <= 0) {
      alert("YOU LOSE TO POTATO!");
      getEnemyHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + enemy.health;
      getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: 0";
    } else {
      getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + player.health;
    }
  }
} else if (getPlayerSpeed <= getEnemySpeed) {
  let enemyAttackValues = enemyAttack();
  let totalDamage = enemyAttackValues[0];
  player.health = player.health - totalDamage;
  alert("Получено урона: " + enemyAttackValues[0]);
  if (player.health <= 0) {
    alert("YOU LOSE TO POTATO!");
    getEnemyHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + enemy.health;
    getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: 0";
  } else {
    getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + player.health;
    //ТЫ АТАКУЕШЬ
    let playerAttackValues = playerAttack();
    let totalDamage = playerAttackValues[0];
    enemy.health = enemy.health - totalDamage;
    alert("Нанесено урона: " + playerAttackValues[0]);
    if (enemy.health <= 0) {
      alert("YOU WON A POTATO!");
      getPlayerHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + player.health;
      getEnemyHealth.innerHTML = "Health: 0";
    } else {
      getEnemyHealth.innerHTML = "Health: " + enemy.health;
    }
  }
}
```

Если еще что-то нужно из кода, то могу залить в комментах или отредактировать пост. Прошу помочь, уже 5 день думаю об этом

Comment: Вы бы функцию на кусочки разбили и переписали, не думаю, что кто-то захочет в этом разбираться, да и вы, судя по всему, запутались. У вас только innerHTML`ов 10 строк, зачем 10 раз писать одно и то же? Разделите задачи. 1. Полностью посчитайте математику урона. 2. Впишите итоговые цифры в HTML. Уверен, что уже на этом этапе, вы поймете в чем проблема.